# Why are environment variables stored inside env file not visible inside the docker-compose service command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `local.env` file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=devdb
POSTGRES_URL=postgres
```

and i have a `docker-compose` file which should use these variables:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'    
        volumes:
            - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        env_file:
            - local.env    
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "devdb", "-U","postgres" ]
            timeout: 45s
            interval: 10s
            retries: 10
    migrate:
        image: migrate/migrate
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
          postgres:
            condition: service_healthy
        env_file:
            - local.env    
        volumes:
            - ./server/migrations:/migrations
        command:
            [ "-database",  "postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/devdb?sslmode=disable" , "-path", "/migrations", "up" ]
```

The command inside the migrate service works correctly in this form. Now I want to take these variables from the local.env file and I change it to:

```
[ "-database",  "postgres://$$POSTGRES_USER:$$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@$$POSTGRES_IP:$$POSTGRES_PORT/$$POSTGRES_DB?sslmode=disable" , "-path", "/migrations", "up" ]
```

And after that at the start of the launch I get the error :

```
error: parse "postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@$POSTGRES_IP:$POSTGRES_PORT/$POSTGRES_DB?sslmode=disable": invalid port ":$POSTGRES_PORT" after host
```

That is, as I understand it, these values are not replaced with values from the file.I tried to use *${}* instead of *$$*, but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong? or is it a mistake in something else?